# How to add site links to google search

Tags: directory

i have a website and i want that users will be able to go to specific parts of the site directly from google.
[image: view screenshot].

how do i add it?

Comment: Are you asking how to programatically add the sitelinks via the AdWords API or how to manually add them in the AdWords user interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are dynamically generated by Google.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&topic=8523

Unfortunately, you don't really have control over them besides general SEO techniques, making sure there's focus on the pages you want to be featured to be more prominent than others.  As far as I can find, the actual algorithms to determine the sitelinks aren't widely known.  If you search around, though, you'll see a bunch of speculation.

If you do have sitelinks there that you absolutely don't want to appear, you can remove them, using Google's Webmaster Tools (http://webmaster.google.com).  However, you can only block them temporarily, not outright delete them, add new ones, or reorder them.

Answer (score 0):

Google's search algorithms somehow figure out most prominent pages on your website and use them as site links. Try using **site wide breadcrumbs** and improve your websites **URL hierarchy/information architecture**.